# debian bibtex.sty not found

Tags: debian, latex

I am running the linux distribution Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm). After I delete all my texlive packages and install texlive-full to get every latex package I can think of and run `pdflatex ~/tmp/tmp.tex`  of this file with contents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bibtex}
\begin{document}
foo is a great thing
\end{document}
```

I get the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `bibtex.sty' not found.
```

EDIT: After I install texlive-bibtex-extra, the error still continues

EDIT: I don't know whose bright idea it was to change the error message I copied and pasted, it is bibtex, not biblatex.

Comment: `bibtex` is a command line utility and not a latex package. Do you maybe mean the `biblatex` package?